# A term for someone who distributes flyers

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word to describe someone who distributes flyers.

**Distributor** doesn't seem right, **part-timer** may not be true, **labourer** is too generic. Is there a job title for such a role?

Comment: in the business it is **box stuffer**, **letterbox stuffer** or just **walker**

Comment: A single word? [Annoying](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=4PNZSgVVgJo).

Comment: lol cute nickname.

Comment: a flyer supplier?

Comment: I would say "litterer".

Answer (score 4):

**Leaflet Distributor** seems like your best option.

[This company](http://www.swiftleafletdistribution.com/) uses the term **Leaflet Distributor**

While [all these advertised jobs](http://jobs.trovit.ie/leaflet-distribution-jobs) also use the same term: **Leaflet Distributor**.

Answer (score 3):

*[Leafleter](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/leafleter#leafleter_1)* is one possibility.

> a person who hands out leaflets

You could also say *leaflet distributor* or *flyer distributor*.

Comment: Maybe it's the coffee, but I really want this to be *leafleteer*. It sounds like a way cooler job.

Comment: Especially if they travel in trios.

Answer (score 1):

According to wikipedia [image]

So **leafleter** sounds good. Infact [here's](http://www.gumtree.com/jobs/uk/leafleter) a formal post for such a job opening.

A *crazy* but fancy (albeit generic) alternative can be *Street Marketer*.

Answer (score 0):

At least [one employer](http://www.tudordistribution.co.uk/recruitment) does indeed use the word *distributor*.

> We are always looking for good adult distributors...
> What should I do if I'm interested in becoming a leaflet or flyer distributor?

This does seem to be an intuitive choice:

> 1. a person or thing that distributes
> 2. a wholesaler or middleman engaged in the distribution of a category of goods, esp to retailers in a specific area
>
> [Collins via [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/distributor)]

The work itself is *delivery*.

> Is leaflet delivery a full time job?

<sub>*[Quotes are from Tudor Distribution, which was one of the results from an internet search.]*</sub>